# How is execution passed from the clr to Startup class (startup.cs)?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

The Startup class in asp.net 5 strikes me as an odd duck.  It isn't class Startup : ISomething or Startup : BaseSomething where the interface or base class is part of some Microsoft.AspNet.* assembly.  No Startup is just a plain class with the correct magical method signatures created by convention.

How is execution passed from DNX to Startup.ConfigureServices?

Lets take for example calling:

```
dnx.exe . web
```

So the . tells dnx that it can find the project.json in the current folder.  From there is finds the command associated with the key "web". So if the local project.json has this:

```
"commands": {
"web" : Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
}
```

I am going to take a stab that combined it would be the equivalent of:
dnx.exe . Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"

I also get how the dnx gathers all the sources (including dependencies) using parameters in the project.json for in memory compilation so we now have the user's assembly "MyAssembly" and all dependent assemblies available to the dnx.  The dnx has loaded Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting as a managed entry point. So execution passes from the unmanaged "stub" to Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting managed assembly.  Correct so far?

The next parameters are instructing Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting that it will be hosting an instance of Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener (specifically on port 500 of localhost).  Ok so how does Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener "know" to look for a class named specifically "Startup" in "MyAssembly".  Is it simply hard coded into Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener?  Into Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting?

The jump to Startup class seems to be the last "magic".  Execution before and after that is starting to get pretty clear but I feel I am still missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNX knows how to load and execute assemblies that have class named `Program` which has a method named `Main`. You are passing `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` as the startup assembly to DNX when you run the `web` command.

Hosting has a [Main method](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/62e534977386ebb02bfc351ec4a6bbea9ea7f635/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs#L23).

[This code](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/62e534977386ebb02bfc351ec4a6bbea9ea7f635/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs#L41) that eventually gets called from the Main method mentioned above has "Startup" hardcoded in it. The actual hardcode is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/62e534977386ebb02bfc351ec4a6bbea9ea7f635/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs#L55-L64).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add some details to Victor's answer:

- DNX's logic that finds the entry points supports [both static and instance Main methods](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Sources/Impl/EntryPointExecutor.cs).
- There's no coupling between the server (WebListener on this case) and the Startup class nor RequestDelegate. The glue if made via [a callback supplied by the hosting layer](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Internal/HostingEngine.cs#L69) to the server factory.
- The transition is not direct from unmanaged code to ASP.NET hosting. There's a managed [entry point/application host on DNX itself](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost/Program.cs#L30). This is where the [support for the new project structure](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/ApplicationHostContext.cs#L50) is implemented (still independent from ASP.NET).

I wrote a series of posts that dives into the details of bootstrapping an ASP.NET 5 application, from [the DNX native host](https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/an-inside-look-at-asp-net-5-execution-part-ii-native-host-managed-entry-point/) up to [request handling](https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/an-inside-look-at-asp-net-5-execution-part-v-request-processing/). All those execution details are covered on the posts.